# eas build is failing after adding expo-updates to project

Tags: react-native, expo

I recently added expo-updates to my expo project and now can't get any of my builds to go through. Running on SDK 48, and expo-updates is on 0.16.4. Here is the error I'm getting in my android build:

```
[stderr] FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
[stderr] 1: Task failed with an exception.

[stderr] 
-----------
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] Execution failed for task ':expo-updates:createReleaseExpoManifest'.
[stderr] > Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Other than installing expo-updates the only other things I've changed are adding release channels in my eas.json file:

```
"build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "channel": "development"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "channel": "preview"
    },
    "production": {
      "channel": "production"
    }
  },
```

And added expo-updates to my plugins list in app.json:

```
"plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            "compileSdkVersion": 33,
            "targetSdkVersion": 33,
            "buildToolsVersion": "33.0.0"
          },
          "ios": {
            "deploymentTarget": "13.0"
          }
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-updates",
        {
          "username": "username"
        }
      ]
    ],
```

I've tried clearing the cache and rebuilding, and also run another round of npm install. Still getting the same error. Anyone else run into this issue?